# How to restart an activity through a dialog pop-up in android?

Tags: android, dialog, popup

So I have a game where if the player loses, a dialog pops up and asks the player whether they want to play again.

How do I restart the game activity if the user selects yes?

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your activity which will set all game values to it's defaults. Then add listener to click button and call this method in it.

Or you may start a new instance of the same activity.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to start a new instance of the activity, but all the ways I used so far either didn't work, or run into a compile error. Can you tell me how exactly to restart an activity from a different activity (in this case from the dialog box)

Comment: you can't restart it, you can only start a new instance via context.startActivity method.

Answer (score 0):

In the "yes" button onClickListener, first call the `finish()` method, then on next line, make an `intent` and launch the same activity